# WCF with minimal overhead

Tags: .net, performance, wcf, rest

I need to create a WCF service (self-hosted inside a windows service) on an industrial intranet.
The problem is, this network is already fairly saturated, and thus a requirement is for there to be as low (network) overhead as possible.

I was wondering which type of WCF service would best suit my needs for this. Given that a "standard" WCF call has a soap envelope around an xml-serialization of my object, this is definitely not the way to go.

My own research leads me to believe that a WCF REST service with json serialization might be the best option. Can anyone confirm this, or give me pointers on how to improve on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between XML SOAP and JSON, or HTTP and net.tcp will not make a very large difference on the network traffic.

SOAP and JASON is there for interoperability, using net.tcp will decrease overhead in the processing power, but it will not really change network overhead that much.

The more important thing you should be looking at is **how frequent** are requests being made to the WCF service. If you can batch your queries that is one very simple way to decrease your overhead.

(I am really suspicious of your claim that the network can not handle the additional load, how do you know it can't handle it? Are you guessing or do you have measurements of the load on your network switches?)

Comment: The frequency is not something that can be changed, I'm afraid. It will be polled by around one hundred components which perform a request every 100ms. (so we're looking at about 1000 requests per second)
About the network overhead: I myself do not have access to the network, this is on a hearsay basis, but I was asked to find a sollution which would decrease the strain as much as possible.

Given your above answer, can I conclude that net.tcp is probably the way to go (as this would already drop the http headers) in terms of optimization, both for network and cpu capacities?

Comment: Are you doing 1000 requests per second with one client or is this something like: 10 clients at 100 requests per second each, or something like 1000 clients with 1 request per second? Each of those options have very different optimization techniques.

Comment: There's ~100 clients with 5-10 requests per second (set-ups can vary).
But I think I now have a decent enough idea of how to improve on things.
Try to get the requests down (not sure if possible), and use net tcp.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

This article suggest net.tcp

[Performance Tuning WCF Services, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323713.aspx)

I agree with Scott on look at keeping message count down.

That is a lot of requests.
Is the data really changing that fast?
If not consider some caching of answer on the WCF.

Comment: The data is indeed changing that fast (hardware components which are performing chemical measurements).
Thanks for the article